# How to alter some values of an array in react

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am working on react project. I have an array which is not a state variable but a constant. The array contains `undefined` values as its element. I want to make `undefined` values as empty array. The array finally should contain values without undefined values. Can anyone help to solve this issue?

if array is [undefined, 1,2,[] ], i need to convert it to [[], 1,2,[] ]

```js
array.forEach(dataSet => 
  (dataSet.dataPoint = (dataSet.dataPoint === undefined) ? [] : dataSet.dataPoint)
);
```

Comment: What is wrong with what you tried ? Your code seems to do what you want

Comment: This won't mutate or reassign the value of `array`

Comment: array.filter(item => item)
https://codepen.io/giannidk/pen/PoYQvBM?editors=0011

Comment: I am getting the error that  Arrow function should not return assignment.eslint

Answer (score 0):

you can map your array into another array:

```
const array2 = array1.map(item => {
  return typeof item === 'undefined'
    ? []
    : item
})
```

https://codepen.io/giannidk/pen/PoYQvBM?editors=0011

Answer (score 0):

1) Use `map` as you are trying to return array as `forEach` just iterates over the array.

```
const array = [undefined, 1,2,[] ]
let newArr = array.map((dataSet) => {
    return dataSet = (dataSet === undefined) ? [] : dataSet
})
console.log(newArr) // [[], 1, 2,[]]
```

Answer (score -1):

You could `map` over the array and return the value of what you'd like in the new array:

```
array = array.map(dataSet => 
  (dataSet.dataPoint = (dataSet.dataPoint === undefined) ? [] : dataSet.dataPoint)
);
```

```js
let array = [{}, { dataPoint: 1 }, {}, { dataPoint: 2 }];

array = array.map(dataSet => 
  (dataSet.dataPoint = (dataSet.dataPoint === undefined) ? [] : dataSet.dataPoint)
);

console.log(array)
```

An approach to mutate the original array (rather than reassign / create a new array):

```js
const array = [{}, {
  dataPoint: 1
}, {}, {
  dataPoint: 2
}];

array.forEach((dataSet, index) => {
  array[index] = dataSet.dataPoint === undefined ? [] : dataSet.dataPoint
});

console.log(array)
```

Comment: @skovy I don't want to remove the values. if the values is undefined, I want to replace it by empty array

Comment: I updated the code snippet, have you tried to run it?

Comment: @skovy array is a const

Comment: Use `let` or create a new variable `let newArray`?

Comment: @skovy is there any other way other than creating new variable

Comment: I updated the answer with an example of that. Use `forEach` and explicitly assign the `array[index]`